# How can one efficiently maintain a cache of Git repository queries?

Tags: git, caching, github, memcached

I have a wiki application that queries and modifies a Git repository per user action (view, edit, move, delete a document). The app does this by parsing commands from the user, and translating them into Git CLI commands (git show, git log, git ls-tree, git add, git rm, git commit...).

For a given page load, there can (potentially) be hundreds of Git commands. Though the commands can often be accomplished in <100ms, the repeated calls add up, causing certain page loads to be obnoxious. Increasingly tricky is that some of the rendered page content is inherently dynamic, meaning that merely caching rendered page outputs is often impossible.

I recognized this scaling issue early in the project, and implemented a caching mechanism to get around the worst of it. Being that a Git repo is static until its next commit, any queries (with their appropriate parameters as part of the memoization) can be cached under the current HEAD commit. This works fairly well, to where many of my page renders with sufficient cache hits can skip calling the Git CLI entirely.

Where this method becomes problematic is during cache invalidation. Let's say you have a commit that updates a file's content. For my commit procedure, I have to invalidate and recalculate:

1. The cached value for the repository's HEAD commit (`git rev-parse HEAD`)
2. The cached value for the file's latest commit (`git log -n1 FILE`)
3. The cached value that asks whether this file exists as of commit X (`git ls-tree -r NEW_COMMIT -- FILE`)

These cache invalidations propagate outwards, as other functions that depend on the recently moved HEAD commit have to recalculate themselves (for example, count of total files in the repository as of new HEAD commit). However, per my example, as I am only updating a page and not moving or removing it, my total file count doesn't have to be recalculated, but my naive caching mechanism can't account for that and has to do it anyway.

My problem: hitting "save" on the application, forcing a `git commit` and a large amount of cache invalidation, takes 100x the time it takes a normal page load, and weighs down other pages loads due to outwardly propagating cache invalidations.

Despite pivoting my cache around my Git repository's HEAD commit, the mechanism is still naive. I feel like an intelligent Git cache should be able to note just the movement/modifications of a branch's HEAD, and be able to update its cache. In a 2009 slideshow (http://www.slideshare.net/err/inside-github, page #107), Github talks about its Walker cache doing something similar, but I can find no further information on how it accomplished these tasks. I have brought my naive caching mechanism from file-based caching, to memory-based filesystem caching, and now to Memcached, and I'm suspicious that my method is reaching its limits.

Is there a more ideal/efficient/scalable methodology to produce valid cache values from a Git repository without playing a game of cache invalidation whackamole?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that any query that uses git tag or SHA-1 identifier can be assumed to be immutable, and cache-able forever.

Comment: Yessir, which is pretty much the only way I'm getting away with what I'm doing currently. My concern is during cache invalidation: when the latest HEAD commit SHA-1 changes (a commit is made), all cached elements have to be recalculated for the new SHA-1. This becomes expensive and gets out of control when I have to walk a few hundred files, and then back a few hundred commits to find what the latest commit for each file is. Given how Git tries to solve most of its problems elegantly, my solution here seems pretty rough.

Comment: What I meant here is that for example results of searching of `v1.0` are immutable and can be cached forever, results of searching `HEAD` change when there is new commit: you can either invalidate, or just use short cache time.

Comment: Ah, understood. I do a `rev-parse HEAD` to ensure I'm dealing with the latest commit SHA-1. I use that instead of "HEAD" to ensure I'm dealing with that immutable handle, and cache for my maximum expiration time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answering my own question, I can't offer a better caching method than what I have, but I can offer how I arrived at the problem, and how I've been trying to address it.

The wiki application I'm supporting has the Mediawiki internal link syntax [supported by Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aLinks#Internal_links), like so:

```
[[ArticleName]]
```

...which generates the following HTML (or something close):

```
<a href="/ArticleName">ArticleName</a>
```

It also supports the "piped link" syntax where you can specify your link text:

```
[[ArticleName|Text for hyperlink]]
```

...which generates the following:

```
<a href="/ArticleName">Text for hyperlink</a>
```

The wiki also supports "hierarchical" articles, such that one can organize your articles like you would in a directory structure. So you can do something like this:

```
[[Dogs/Breeds/Spaniel/Water|Water Spaniel]]
```

...and it will generate a link like so:

```
<a href="/Dogs/Breeds/Spaniel/Water">Water Spaniel</a>
```

Using the non-pipe syntax, however, will generate a link for each component in the hierarchical path. That is, if you do not specify your link text, like so:

```
[[Dogs/Breeds/Spaniel/Water]]
```

The page will render the internal link as the following:

```
<a href="/Dogs">Dogs</a>/
<a href="/Dogs/Breeds">Breeds</a>/
<a href="/Dogs/Breeds/Spaniel">Spaniel</a>/
<a href="/Dogs/Breeds/Spaniel/Water">Water</a>
```

In addition to this, each link to a file has a CSS class associated with it to indicate whether that file exists in the current HEAD commit. This is useful to show which files ware "wanted," and at a glance indicate which files you would expect to return content when clicking on them or whether you would be creating new content.

For example, if the file `Dogs` does not exist, the internal link specified like so:

```
[[Dogs]]
```

... will generate a link with an "edit" CSS class to indicate that clicking on the link will drop into an editor (and in my case, color the link red).

```
<a class="edit" href="Dogs">Dogs</a>
```

A similar task has to be performed for the "non-piped", hierarchical links. Let's say you're created `Dogs` and `Dogs/Breeds/Spaniel/Water,` but you haven't created the parent articles `Dogs/Breeds` or `Dogs/Breeds/Spaniels`. The non-piped link specified like so:

```
[[Dogs/Breeds/Spaniels/Water]]
```

...will generate the path component links with the appropriate CSS classes:

```
<a href="/Dogs">Dogs</a>/
<a class="edit" href="/Dogs/Breeds">Breeds</a>/
<a class="edit" href="/Dogs/Breeds/Spaniel">Spaniel</a>/
<a href="/Dogs/Breeds/Spaniel/Water">Water</a>
```

This means that for each internal link, we have to ask the Git repository the following questions:

1. Does the full path exist in the HEAD commit?
2. If this is a hierarchical path, and the link does not specify a pipe link text, do each of the path components leading up to the full path exist in the HEAD commit?

At a glance, this doesn't seem like a huge issue. However, imagine pages with potentially hundreds of automatically generated internal links (imagine: navigational macros that can list files, or perform tiny searches, etc.). And depending on the complexity of your file structures, you may have 5-10+ path components that will need to be checked for each internal link. This means hundreds of Git calls per page rendering, and hundreds of cache invalidations when you perform a new commit and move the HEAD.

There is no way to get around paying the price making calls against the Git repository. The question becomes how one maintains an efficient and accurate cache of the queries, and in what ways you can cheat to get your answers.

I solve this from two directions: one from an "on demand" perspective, and one from a "bulk load" perspective that runs at certain intervals.

#### On-demand Caching, Naive

Git can answer the question of "Does this file exist?" fairly handily by asking it to list the file (or fail to do so) as of the HEAD commit, or its SHA-1 sum. However, a Git repository is not centered around the files it contains, but instead around its "commits." In order to ask "Does this file exist?" for a commit that is not the HEAD, and is not representative of a working directory, Git has to walk its log and note the file contents at each step. This is my best theory on why this operation is difficult for Git, and tends to be expensive.

So, let's say we have 100 files in the HEAD commit ABCD, and we've answered and cached the question of "Does this file exist in ABCD?" for all 100 files.

A user wants to make an edit and commit. This moves the HEAD from ABCD to BEEF. All of a sudden, all cached answers for "Does this file exist for ABCD?" are no longer relevant because BEEF can potentially represent an entirely new set of files. We will need to answer the question of "Does this file exist for BEEF?" for all 100 files, plus or minus what files were added or removed.

We really can't do this, because this would take forever and would require the committing user to wait for all ~100 file caches to be rebuilt before continuing.

We *can* simply ask the answers "on demand," meaning that we roll the dice on whether the page being rendered after an edit will have significantly fewer than ~100 internal links, such that the user won't notice the incurred penalty from the cache invalidation. This is less than ideal, as you will get vastly different response times from edits, and some pages will eventually become unusable. I don't recommend this method.

#### On-demand Caching, Slightly Better

The reason why the above method isn't great is because a Git repository's branch HEAD will move frequently, invalidating the cache. However, while a HEAD may move, it may be the case that most files in a repository will not be touched with a commit. If we assume there may be many commits, but relatively few files touched, we can yield some caching gains.

Instead of caching the question "Does a file exist as of HEAD commit ABCD?", let's instead ask "Does a file exist as of its latest commit?" That is: for the last commit in which a file modified, did it exist at the end of that commit?

This means that for each time we ask the question, we can perform a `git log -n1 -- FILEPATH` to get the last item in the file's commit log, and then ask the question as of that commit.

For example: Let's say that for the file `Dogs` we look up the latest commit, and it is ACED. We ask the question "Does the file Dogs exist as the end of commit ACED?" The answer is Yes, and we store that answer.

Then, somebody makes a modification to the Water Spaniels page `Dogs/Breeds/Spaniels/Water`), moving the repository's HEAD commit. The article `Dogs` did not change, so the "latest" commit for `Dogs` is still ACED. This means that the question "Does the file `Dogs` exist as the end of commit ACED?" is still valid, and we can retrieve it from the cache despite the fact that the HEAD commit has moved.

While this is much better, and less susceptible to cache invalidation, we have introduced a new problem. For each cache miss, we now have 2 Git queries to perform (one for the latest commit, and one for the file existing) rather than one. The `git log -n1 -- FILEPATH` query suffers from the same performance/commit storage that are inherent from the "Does this file exist" queries, in that we have to walk the commit log (sometimes a long ways) to answer the question.

As we are now caching at the file level rather than the repository level, we can at least suffer the peformance hits of cache invalidation at the smaller file level rather than at the repository level. Even better: when editing and committing files, we know which files are to be edited, and we can invalidate only the caches for these queries. Rebuilding the cache for 1 file is much less expensive than for ~100 files.

#### Bulk Caching, Naive

We can make improvements for the on-demand cache loading to solve our internal linking problem, but we will still need to ask the questions of the Git repository whenever a page is loaded. If a page's requisite queries have fallen off the end of the cache (or were never accessed in the first place), we still incur the penalities of cache misses.

We also need a way to "prime" the cache, that is, to predict which queries will need to be answered, and try to answer them ahead of time.

A naive method is to simply ask "What is the latest commit for file X?" and "Does file X exist as of commit Y?" for each file in the repository. This is technically sufficient, but can be very time consuming, as it requires Git calls for every single query.

Remember, however, that not all queries of the repository are answered for files that exist. There may be links to paths that do not exist, especially when generating the broken out components of hierarchical internal links.

#### Bulk Caching, With ls-tree

We've established that we have a minimum of 2 Git queries for each file, and that you can mitigate performance hits with caching of both queries. However, one can cheat a bit if you can answer a significant number of the questions in a different way.

Git can return a list of all files as of a commit in a repository using `git ls-tree -r COMMIT`. Any file listed in this Git result can be considered "existing" as of the latest HEAD. We can also pair this with the "latest commit for file X" query to refresh the cache to answer whether a file still exists (as if it exists in the `ls-tree` on the HEAD commit, it should still exist in whichever latest HEAD commit. This lets us reduce our 2 requisite queries per file down to 1 (with only the overhead of the initial `ls-tree` command.

However, this method is not yet perfect. For the internal links, we still have the interstitial path components (`Dogs/Breeds`, `Dogs/Breeds/Spaniels`, etc.) that need to have answers.

We can also abuse the `ls-tree` output to help with this. The ls-tree listing only contains files that are known to exist as of a commit. It does not list any files which are not in the repository. This means that for all of the interstitial components we can ask, "Among the ls-tree results, does this component path exist?" If it does, we can add it to the "Yes, this file exists as of the HEAD" items to cache, and if it doesn't, we can add it to the "No, this file does not exist as of HEAD" cache.

#### Bulk Caching, Log Walking

Repeatedly asking `git log -n1 -- FILE` for the latest commit for a file is inefficient. For each file, one has to re-walk the commit log backwards, starting over at the beginning.

This step I am experimenting with, but it seems to be quite effective. Git can easily list the files that were affected in a given commit. If one can get a list of all branch commit refs, one can walk through the repository listing files that are affected by the commit. Doing this, we can store the last commit in which we saw that a file was touched.

This seems a little brute force, but it ensures that the commits are walked only once (rather than starting over again and again at the HEAD commit, which takes significantly longer).

--

Well, this ended up being super long. Hoping to commit here in the hopes that it helps somebody else trying to solve these problems.